# Html: Pick random string from array and show it one by one with delay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have code that returns strings, but I want to display strings randomly. If you have better code, cheers. The main task is to have a list of  words, and a script that displays these words in a random order, but without replacing one word with another, namely one after another. The delay should be configurable.

```js
$("#slideShow .fadeInAmate").each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(200 * i).fadeIn(2000, function() {
    $(this).prev().addClass('foo');
  });
});
```

```css
#slideShow p {
  display: none;
}

.foo {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jforaker.github.io/jQuery-FadeInAmate/src/jquery.fadeInAmate.js"></script>

<div id="slideShow">
  <p class="fadeInAmate">This is my first line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">Here goes my second line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">Then comes third line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">Following to that fourth line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">And finally here goes my fifth line</p>
</div>
```

Comment: To clarify: Do you want to randomize the order of _animation_ (first to last in time), the order of _placement_ (top to bottom), or both?

Answer (score 0):

Simple shuffle the HTML elements first with `Math.random()` and then go with your code.

```js
function shuffle(){
  var slideShow = $(".fadeInAmate");
  for(var i = 0; i < slideShow.length; i++){
    var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * slideShow.length -1) + 1;
    var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * slideShow.length -1) +1;
    slideShow.eq(target).before(slideShow.eq(target2));
  }
}

function animate(){
  $("#slideShow .fadeInAmate").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(200 * i).fadeIn(2000, function() {
      $(this).prev().addClass('foo');
    });

  });
}

shuffle();
animate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #slideShow p {
display: none;
}

.foo {
color: #000;
}
</style>
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jforaker.github.io/jQuery-FadeInAmate/src/jquery.fadeInAmate.js"></script>
<div id="slideShow">
<p class="fadeInAmate">This is my first line</p>
<p class="fadeInAmate">Here goes my second line</p>
<p class="fadeInAmate">Then comes third line</p>
<p class="fadeInAmate">Following to that fourth line</p>
<p class="fadeInAmate">And finally here goes my fifth line</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it helped dont forget to vote and accept the answer :).